# Tomcat starts but Home Page does NOT open on browser with URL http://localhost:8080

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

[image]Tomcat starts but Home Page does NOT open on browser with URL http://localhost:8080

I was running Apache Tomcat from Eclipse and while accessing URL http://localhost:8080 found HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error.

Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Tomcat starts but doesn’t display webpage.
What can be wrong with tomcat?

Comment: try `http://localhost:8080/<your_war_name>`.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Answer (score 0):

Production Tomcat has a ROOT application deployed for that by default. When launching from Eclipse, only your own projects are deployed.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#If_I_start_my_Tomcat_server_and_try_to_display_Tomcat.27s_default_page.2C_why_do_I_see_a_directory_listing_or_404_error_page.3F